# Radical mechanism with fish hook arrows using mol2chemfig

Tags: chemfig, mol2chemfig

I am new to `chemfig` and I want to draw a radical mechanism. It should look like this:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{mol2chemfig}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chemfig{
           O% 4
    =[:108]% 3
    -[:162]% 2
     -[:90]% 1
     -[:18]% 6
              (
         =[:72]O% 7
              )
    -[:306]@{N}N%% 5
              (
        -[:234]@{b}% -> 3
              )
          -[@{b}]@{Br}Br% 8
}
\arrow{->[$h\nu$]}
\chemfig{
           O% 6
    =[:252]% 3
    -[:306]\lewis{0.,N}% 2
    -[:234]% 1
              (
        =[:288]O% 7
              )
    -[:162]% 5
     -[:90]% 4
              (
         -[:18]% -> 3
              )
}
\arrow{0[+][][-10pt]}
\ch{Br^{.}}
\schemestop

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \mcfpush{b}{100:10mm}{N}{90:8mm}
    \mcfpush{b}{-80:10mm}{Br}{-90:8mm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And the output from it:

[image]

I want to convert the mechanism arrow into a red fish hook arrow and create horizontal space between the rxn arrow and the two molecules.

Comment: In order to color the arrow, you can use `\colorlet{mcfpusharrowcolor}{red}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I have used `\colorlet{mcfpusharrowcolor}{<color>}` to change the color of the arrow, `-{Straight Barb[right]},` to change the arrow tip to a harpoon/fish hook style and `\setchemfig{arrow offset=<distance>}` to increase the distance between molecules and reaction arrows.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{mol2chemfig}

\colorlet{mcfpusharrowcolor}{red}%<----- Added to change the color of the curved arrows

\tikzset{ 
    mcfpusharrow/.style = {
        mcfpusharrowcolor,
        -{Straight Barb[right]}, % <---- Added for harpoon style curved arrows
        shorten <=3pt,
        shorten >=2pt,
        preaction={draw=mcfbgcolor, -,line width=1.5pt}
    }}

\setchemfig{arrow offset=10pt}   % <----- Modify distance between molecule and arrow (default is 4pt)

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}




\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chemfig{
           O% 4
    =[:108]% 3
    -[:162]% 2
     -[:90]% 1
     -[:18]% 6
              (
         =[:72]O% 7
              )
    -[:306]@{N}N%% 5
              (
        -[:234]@{b}% -> 3
              )
          -[@{b}]@{Br}Br% 8
}
\arrow{->[$h\nu$]}
\chemfig{
           O% 6
    =[:252]% 3
    -[:306]\lewis{0.,N}% 2
    -[:234]% 1
              (
        =[:288]O% 7
              )
    -[:162]% 5
     -[:90]% 4
              (
         -[:18]% -> 3
              )
}
\arrow{0[+][][-10pt]}
\ch{Br^{.}}
\schemestop



\begin{tikzpicture}
    \mcfpush{b}{100:10mm}{N}{90:8mm}
    \mcfpush{b}{-80:10mm}{Br}{-90:8mm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Genius at work!! Thanks a lot!!