# Chemfig drawing with arrows and Lewis dots

Tags: chemfig

If I wanted to draw something like this with the `chemfig` package, how would I do that?

[image]

I'm especially wondering how to draw the arrows in the most simple and beautiful way possible.

Update:
With help from one of the replies i've managed to fully complete the right side of the arrow. My code so far looks like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol{e}{-[,.15,,,draw=none]}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
    \chemfig{[:30]**6(--(-C(=[90]O)-O)----)}
    %
    \quad \arrow \quad
    %
    \chemfig{[:30]**6(--(!e\Lewis{0.,})----)}
    \arrow{0}[,0]\+
    \chemfig{C(=[90]O)(=[270]O)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks:
[image: Can]

I'm still missing a few elements as you can probably see being:

1. The Lewis dot on the oxygen molecule is not showing.
2. The arrows are still missing.
3. The left side is not properly lined up with the arrow and the right side.

If anyone has any improvements to my code, feel free to say so! :)

Comment: Probably useful for the product part of the reaction: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59816/134144

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot. I've updated the question with my drawing so far. Still have a bunch of issues though!

Comment: Great update. The missing radical dot on the left side can be added using `\lewis{0.,O}` as in `\chemfig{[:30]**6(--(-C(=[90]O)-\lewis{0.,O})----)}`.

Comment: For the curved arrows, you might find `\mcfpush` from the `mol2chemfig` package useful. You can find an example here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/508895/134144

Comment: Whew, that seems difficult! For some reason, my compiler can't use the `mol2chemfig` package, weird.. Even when i copy the code directly from the other post, it wont compile :/. Anyway, im gonna take a look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{lewis radius =0.25ex,lewis sep =1ex}
\schemestart
\chemfig{
    [:-30]**6(---(@{a1}-[@{a2}0]C(=[2]O)(=[6,,,,draw=none]\phantom{O})
    -[@{a3}0]@{a4}\Lewis{0.,O}-[,0.7,,,draw=none])---)}
\arrow{->}
\chemfig{-[0,0.5,,,draw=none]**6(---(-[,0.3,,,draw=none]\Lewis{0.,})---)}
\arrow{0}[,0.2]
\+
\arrow{0}[,0.2]
\chemfig{C(=[2]O)(=[6]O)}
\schemestop
\chemmove{
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon]}, shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
        ($(a2)+(-1pt,0)$) .. controls +(270:10mm) and +(270:10mm) .. (a1);
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon]}, shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
        ($(a2)+(1pt,0)$) .. controls +(270:10mm) and +(270:10mm) .. ($(a3)+(-1pt,0)$);
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon,swap]}, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=1pt]
        ($(a4)+(1.25ex,0)$) .. controls +(270:10mm) and +(270:10mm) .. ($(a3)+(1pt,0)$);
}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

change \Lewis to \charge

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{lewis radius =0.25ex,lewis sep =1ex}
\schemestart
\chemfig{
    [:-30]**6(---(@{a1}-[@{a2}0]C(=[2]O)(=[6,,,,draw=none]\phantom{O})
    -[@{a3}0]@{a4}\charge{0=\.}{O}-[,0.7,,,draw=none])---)}
\arrow{->}
\chemfig{-[0,0.5,,,draw=none]**6(---\charge{0:2pt=\.}{}---)}
\arrow{0}[,0.2]
\+
\arrow{0}[,0.2]
\chemfig{C(=[2]O)(=[6]O)}
\schemestop
\chemmove{
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon]}, shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
        ($(a2)+(-1pt,0)$) .. controls +(270:10mm) and +(270:10mm) .. (a1);
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon]}, shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
        ($(a2)+(1pt,0)$) .. controls +(270:10mm) and +(270:10mm) .. ($(a3)+(-1pt,0)$);
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon,swap]}, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=1pt]
        ($(a4)+(1.25ex,0)$) .. controls +(270:10mm) and +(270:10mm) .. ($(a3)+(1pt,0)$);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]