# More chemfig figures with fishhook arrows

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

[I asked a similar question yesterday,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511760/chemfig-drawing-with-arrows-and-lewis-dots) but i havn't quite learned how to make these molecules yet. Therefore i'll see if there is a kind soul in here again today, who wants to help me with this one, too.

So i need to draw these two figures:

Figure 1:
[image]

Figure 2:
[image]

The best i could do myself was this, and i hope someone could add the fishhook arrows as well as the square brackets on the very last molecule of figure 2.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{lewis radius =.35ex,lewis sep =1ex}
\begin{flushleft}

Figure 1:
\schemestart
    \chemfig{
        -[0,0.5,,,draw=none]
        **6(---(-[,0.3,,,draw=none]\Lewis{0.,})---)
    }
\arrow{0}[,.8]
%
    {\chemfig{
        C(-[::120]H)(-[::-120]H)=C(-[::60]H)(-[::-60]H)}
    }
\arrow{->}
%
    \chemfig{
        -[0,0.5,,,draw=none]
        **6(---(-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-\Lewis{0.,O})---)
    }
\schemestop

\vspace{1cm}

Figure 2:
\schemestart
    \chemfig{
       -[0,0.5,,,draw=none]
        **6(---(-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-\Lewis{0.,O})---)
    }
\arrow{0}[,.8]
%
    {\chemfig{
        C(-[::120]H)(-[::-120]H)=C(-[::60]H)(-[::-60]H)}
    }
%
\arrow{->}
\schemestop

\vspace{1cm}

\schemestart
    \chemfig{
        -[0,0.5,,,draw=none]
        **6(---(-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-                       \Lewis{0.,O})---)
    }
\arrow{0}[,-.6]
%
\arrow{->}
%
    \chemfig{
        -[0,2,,,draw=none]
        -C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-
    }
\schemestop

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

And the compiled version looks like this:
[image]

The last guy who helped me used the `chemmove` command, i'm not sure, if the same command will do the trick this time around.

Comment: For the square brackets you could use the `\polymerdelim` command from `chemfig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{lewis radius =0.25ex,lewis sep =1ex}

\schemestart
\chemfig{
        [:-30]**6(---(-[,0.2,,,draw=none]@{a1}\Lewis{0.,}
        -[@{a2,1}0,,,,draw=none])---)
}
\arrow{0}[,0.8]
\chemfig{
        C(-[:120]H)(-[:240]H)=[@{a3}]@{a4}C(-[:60]H)(-[:300]H)
}
\hspace{1em}
\arrow
\hspace{1em}
\chemfig{
        [:-30]**6(---(-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
        -[0,0.1,,,draw=none]\Lewis{0.,\phantom{C}})---)
}
\schemestop
\chemmove{
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon]}, shorten <=3pt, shorten >=1pt]
            ($(a1)+(0.35ex,0)$) .. controls +(270:10mm) and +(270:10mm) .. (a2);
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon]}, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=1pt]
            ($(a3)+(-1pt,0)$) .. controls +(90:20mm) and +(90:20mm) .. (a2);
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon]}, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=1pt]
            ($(a3)+(1pt,0)$) .. controls +(90:10mm) and +(90:10mm) .. (a4);
}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

\schemestart
\chemfig{
    [:-30]**6(---(-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
    -[0,0.1,,,draw=none]@{a5}\Lewis{0.,\phantom{C}}-[@{a6,1}0,,,,draw=none])---)
}
\arrow{0}[,0.8]
\chemfig{
    C(-[:120]H)(-[:240]H)=[@{a7}]@{a8}C(-[:60]H)(-[:300]H)
}
\hspace{1em}
\arrow
\schemestop
\chemmove{
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon]}, shorten <=3pt, shorten >=1pt]
            ($(a5)+(0.55em,0)$) .. controls +(270:10mm) and +(270:10mm) .. (a6);
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon]}, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=1pt]
            ($(a7)+(-1pt,0)$) .. controls +(90:20mm) and +(90:20mm) .. (a6);
    \draw[arrows = {-Stealth[harpoon]}, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=1pt]
            ($(a7)+(1pt,0)$) .. controls +(90:10mm) and +(90:10mm) .. (a8);
}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

\schemestart
\chemfig{
    [:-30]**6(---(-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
    -C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
    -[0,0.1,,,draw=none]\Lewis{0.,\phantom{C}})---)
}
\hspace{1em}
\arrow
\hspace{1em}
\chemfig{
    -[@{op,0.6}]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[@{cl,0.4}]
}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 31pt, depth=36pt, indice = \!n]{op}{cl}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```